# How to configure platforms for flutter firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am following [the guidance](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/#initialization) to configure firebase for flutter application.

`flutterfire configure` fails for me, with both master and stable channels of flutter.

What can be wrong?

```
i Found 5 Firebase projects. Selecting project date-game-com.                                                                                                                   
✔ Which platforms should your configuration support (use arrow keys & space to select)? · android, ios                                                                          
✔ Which Android application id (or package name) do you want to use for this configuration, e.g. 'com.example.app'? · com.dategame                                              
i Firebase android app com.dategame registered.                                                                                                                                 
i Firebase ios app com.date-game.RunnerTests registered.                                                                                                                        
✔ Generated FirebaseOptions file lib/firebase_options.dart already exists, do you want to override it? · yes                                                                    
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)

^

#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.close (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:501:7)
#2      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:36:10)
#3      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:610:36)
#4      FirebaseAndroidOptions.projectIdFromFileContents (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase/firebase_android_options.dart:29:29)
#5      FirebaseAndroidGradlePlugins.applyGoogleServicesPlugin (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase/firebase_android_gradle_plugins.dart:101:50)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      FirebaseAndroidGradlePlugins.apply (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase/firebase_android_gradle_plugins.dart:240:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Here is generated  `firebase_options.dart`:

````
// File generated by FlutterFire CLI.
// ignore_for_file: lines_longer_than_80_chars, avoid_classes_with_only_static_members
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart' show FirebaseOptions;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'
    show defaultTargetPlatform, kIsWeb, TargetPlatform;

/// Default [FirebaseOptions] for use with your Firebase apps.
///
/// Example:
/// ```dart
/// import 'firebase_options.dart';
/// // ...
/// await Firebase.initializeApp(
///   options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
/// );
/// ```
class DefaultFirebaseOptions {
  static FirebaseOptions get currentPlatform {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      throw UnsupportedError(
        'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for web - '
        'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
      );
    }
    switch (defaultTargetPlatform) {
      case TargetPlatform.android:
        return android;
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
        return ios;
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for macos - '
          'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
        );
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for windows - '
          'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
        );
      case TargetPlatform.linux:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for linux - '
          'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
        );
      default:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions are not supported for this platform.',
        );
    }
  }

  static const FirebaseOptions android = FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyDol6n8GLn8HT5P4xl22GdC4x8XAdNM8PA',
    appId: '1:170500034711:android:057f7c563f4d02324399d2',
    messagingSenderId: '170500034711',
    projectId: 'date-game-com',
    storageBucket: 'date-game-com.appspot.com',
  );

  static const FirebaseOptions ios = FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyDuvrG6zSBknSVqhQnC62HGz6-47Tw2o-A',
    appId: '1:170500034711:ios:38716b467804b00f4399d2',
    messagingSenderId: '170500034711',
    projectId: 'date-game-com',
    storageBucket: 'date-game-com.appspot.com',
    iosClientId:
        '170500034711-djeuqsd9gt4roqrau95irc8aakntn5kl.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    iosBundleId: 'com.date-game.RunnerTests',
  );
}
````

Comment: Can you add your code for `lib/firebase_options.dart`?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by deactivating and reactivating flutter-fire and deleting Google services.json file but not sure exactly what is happening

```
dart pub global deactivate flutterfire_cli
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```